# I have a type script error in a use of useContext in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I initialized a value of  `createContext` with `{}`, then I provided a context with a new value `{username: 'sasuke1'}`. Then when I try to access the property of `Context.username` TypeScript gives me this error:

```
Property 'username' does not exist on type '{}'.       return <div> {userInfo.username === userInfoContext.**username**? </div>
```

---

```
export const UserContext = createContext({})
```

---

```
function App() {

  const userInfoUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/user-info'
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({username:''})
  const [finishedLoading, setFinishedLoading] = useState(false)
  const navigate = useNavigate() // redirect to other components
  const location = useLocation() // react router hook

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(userInfoUrl, {credentials: 'include'}).then(async res=>{
      if(res.status!==200){
        navigate('/login')
        
        return
      }
      setUserInfo(await res.json())
      navigate('/feed')
    }).catch(err=>{
      navigate('/login')
    }).finally(()=>{
      setFinishedLoading(true)
    })
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (finishedLoading && !userInfo && location.pathname !== '/login') {
      navigate('/login')
    }
  },[location])


  return <div style={{ backgroundColor:'#FAFAFA', height: '100vh'}}>
    {/* <Navbar/> */}
    <UserContext.Provider value={userInfo}>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to={'/register'}>Registration</Link></li>
        <li><Link to={'/login'}>Login</Link></li>
        <li><Link to={'/feed'}>Feed</Link></li>
        <li><Link to={'/user/:username'}>User</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  
    <Outlet></Outlet>
    </UserContext.Provider>


  </div>;
}
```

---

```
export function User({ user }: { user?: {} }) {
    const userParams = useParams()
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({username: '', email: '', following: []})
    const userInfoContext = useContext(UserContext)
    let noUser = ''


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(userInfoContext)
        const username = userParams.username
        // const searchUserAPI = async () => { }
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/users/${username}`, { credentials: 'include', mode: 'cors', })
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json()
            })
            .then(async (res) => {
                await setUserInfo(res)
                return res
            })
            .then(()=>{
                console.log(userInfo)

            })
            .catch(()=>{
                noUser = "Sorry, this page isn't available.\nThe link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed. Go back to Instagram."
            })
    }, [])

    return <div>
        {userInfo.username === userInfoContext.username?
         <h1>{JSON.stringify(userInfo)}</h1> : <h1>{noUser}</h1>}
    </div>
```

Comment: `createContext<YourDatatypeHere>({})`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like createContext is defaulting its type to whatever it was initialized with, in this case an empty object `{}` which has no properties.

To fix this error you can set the type explicitly `e.g createContext<{username: string}>({})` or just set the type to any `createContext<any>({})`. Obviously you won't get the benefits of typescript setting the type to any, but it will fix the error and behave as expected.

Hope this helps! :)